# viewpager inside of framelayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

My example is composed of a Mainactivity.java (FragmentActivity), a Fragment Called Fragment_ViewPager (Fragment), an adapter Adapter_ViewPager (FragmentPagerAdapter) and three fragments are common fragments Fragment extentienden and have a method onCreateView.

Mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager FM = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction FT = FM.beginTransaction();

        Fragment_ViewPager f_pager = new Fragment_ViewPager();
        FT.add(R.id.fragment_container, f_pager);
        FT.commit();

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</FrameLayout>
```

Fragment_ViewPager.java

```
private static final int[] ICONS = new int[] { R.drawable.ic_launcher,  R.drawable.ic_launcher,  R.drawable.ic_launcher };
    private FragmentPagerAdapter mFragmentPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private TabPageIndicator mTabPagerIndicator;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.f_pager, container, false);

        mFragmentPagerAdapter = new Adapter_ViewPager(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), ICONS);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager)v.findViewById(R.id.view_pager_inicio);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mFragmentPagerAdapter);
        mTabPagerIndicator = (TabPageIndicator)v.findViewById(R.id.tab_indicator_inicio);
        mTabPagerIndicator.setViewPager(mViewPager);


        return v;

    }
```

fragment_viewpager.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/tab_indicator_inicio"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager_inicio"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Adapter_ViewPager.java

```
private static int[] ICONS = null;
    private Fragment mFragment = null;

    public Ad_inicio(FragmentManager fm,  int[] icons) {
        super(fm);
        ICONS = icons;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            mFragment = new Fragmento_uno();
            break;
        case 1:
            mFragment = new Fragmento_dos();
            break;
        case 2:
            mFragment = new Fragmento_tres();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return mFragment;
    }



    @Override
    public int getIconResId(int index) {
        return ICONS[index];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ICONS.length;
    }
```

Fragment_One.java

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmento_One, container, false);

        return v;

    }
```

fragment_one.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="uno" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Works well the swipe of the fragments, but the problem is when I change orientation from portrait to horizintal my device, the swipe not working and is showing only fragemnto was visible before the vertical orientation ... 
I wonder what I'm doing wrong because the viewpager must operate within a FragmentAcitivity, but for this example I had to extend Fragment to use dentrod a FrameLayout, looks like its the getActivity (). GetSupportFragmentManager () that I send him to Adpater not operating correctly the second time.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use other constructors for the `Adapter_ViewPager` class, than the default `constructor(FragmentManager)`!

I think, when your activity restarts, the Android calls the default constructor, and the `ICONS`'ll be null.

Try to put a breakpoint there, and see, what's the value og the `ICONS` after a rotation.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering .. 
I just tried putting a breakpoint, and if it returns a number ICONS 3, it seems the problem is that I recognize again the FragmentManaget fragments found in the main activity .. 
What I try to do is something like this.

http://s21.postimg.org/a497zxtxz/Imagen_View_Pager.png

Comment: I fixed the problem by changing the getSupportFragmentManager () that was receiving the FragmentPagerAdapter, by getChildFragmentManager () but now the problem is that the change of orientation of the, fragment was displayed at that time is maintained above the other, as if not erased.